# Left duals and right duals are also isomorphic in a semisimple category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

In the n-Lab page

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigid+monoidal+category

it is written that

> Left duals and right duals are also isomorphic in a semisimple
> category.

For a left dual semisimplicity allows us split the evaluation and coevaluaion maps hence giving a candidate for a right dual. But how does one prove the axioms for a right dual?